# TCL regsub pattern to another pattern

Tags: tcl

How can I regsub pattern to another pattern

`set a "how1how ku2ku how2how" ; regsub "how*how" $a "oo_how\*how_oo"`

I want all names "how(num)how" will be swap to the same name with prefix and suffix
but the above regsub now work for me

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want to achieve here. _What output string do you want to get?_ Is it `oo_how1oo_how ku2ku oo_how2oo_how`?

Answer (score 0):

A capture group followed by a backreference usually:

```
% set a "how1how ku2ku how2how"
how1how ku2ku how2how
% regsub -all {how([0-9]+)how} $a {oo_how\1how_oo}
oo_how1how_oo ku2ku oo_how2how_oo
```

[Documentation for the syntax](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

---

Following the comments, I think that maybe what you are after is something like this?

```
set word "how"
set a "how1how ku2ku how2how"
regsub -all [format {%s([0-9]+)%s} $word $word] $a [format {oo_%s\1%s_oo} $word $word]
```

`format` allows some substitution where strings `%s` would be substituted with the provided parameters.

Comment: Is there any different way to replace string but the orig word and the new will be the except of the prefix and the suffix?


`command {word to replace} $a oo_{word to replace}_oo`

Comment: @user3835935 If you want to replace all instances of a substring and not a regular expression, `string map [list $word oo_${word}_oo] $text`. If matching a regular expression... Well, that's what this answer is for.

Comment: @Shawn, what should be $word to catch the "how1how" & "how2how"?

Comment: @Jerry, I wrote a script to color some strings in my report.
The user can give the exact string he want to color.
in my report it can be that we want to color "name_num_name" and I want just to add the color syntax before and after the word.
my input to the proc is word to color + line.

Comment: @Jerry, The edited answer solve the exact example but word can be any string.
how, how_2_how, how1how, you5you.
so the substitute should include any string.
Better to set "word": `set word "how" ; set word "how.how", set word "how[0-8]how" ...`

Comment: I think it can be as simple as `regsub -all $word $string {oo_&_oo}` for just adding prefix and suffix to pattern matches.

Comment: @glennjackman - Thanks this is the exact of what I searching for.

Comment: @user3835935 that is very very far from what you described in your question lol